# Variáveis PHP com valores errados após manipulação de String

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$respostaXML = "<data-hora>2015-11-10T11:33:41.086-02:00</data-hora>";
$posTag = strpos($respostaXML,"<data-hora>");
$comprimento = (strpos($respostaXML,"</data-hora>") - strpos($respostaXML,"<data-hora>"));
$respDataHora = substr($respostaXML,$posTag,$comprimento);
$respData = substr($respDataHora,9,2) . "/" . substr($respDataHora,6,2) . "/" . substr($respDataHora,1,4);
$respHora = substr($respDataHora,12,8);
```

A minha intenção é que na respData eu obtenha "10/11/2015" e na respHora "11:33:33". Acontece que o resultado está sendo esse:

```
respDataHora = 2015-11-10T11:33:41.086-02:00
respData = a>/ho/data                           
respHora = 015-11-1
```

A respDataHora está OK, já a respData deu esse resultado bizarro (trechos do NOME da variável anterior) e a respHora deve ter dado esses números pelo mesmo motivo.

O mesmo código, com diferenças de sintaxe e funções, é claro, funciona perfeitamente em ASP clássico. O que está acontecendo aí?

Comment: O problema era que eu estava puxando a String na respDataHora com tag e tudo, porque por serem tags elas não aparecem na visualização da página. O código correto precisa ter um "+11" no final da posTag e "-11" no final da variavel comprimento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema era a tag `<data-hora>` você considerava ela na hora de fazer o `strpos()` e acabava pegando a primeira posição dela que era `0`, ai acabava fazendo essa bagunça, fiz um exemplo removendo estas tags com o `str_replace()`.

**Exemplo:**

```
$xml = "<data-hora>2015-11-10T11:33:41.086-02:00</data-hora>";
$xml = str_replace("<data-hora>", "", $xml);
$respDataHora = str_replace("</data-hora>", "", $xml);
$respData = substr($respDataHora, 0, 10);
$respHora = substr($respDataHora, 11,8);
echo $respDataHora . '<br>';
echo $respData . '<br>';
echo $respHora . '<br>';
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/C4cvIo).

Comment: você esta capturando o fuso horário em : substr($respDataHora, 24);

Comment: Pois é Gabriel, era isso mesmo. Descobri isso trocando as "<" e ">" das tags por pipes. Obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Tinha este detalhe, agora esta correto, obrigado.

Comment: Por que eu ganhei -1?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que seria mais fácil fazer por `preg_match`, tendo em vista que você tem uma `string` bem definida.

```
$respostaXML = "<data-hora>2015-11-10T11:33:41.086-02:00</data-hora>";

$regex = '~<(data-hora)>(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})[\d\-\.:]*</\1>~';

preg_match($regex, $respostaXML, $match);

$data = $match[2];
$data = explode('-', $data);
$data = "{$data[2]}/{$data[1]}/{$data[0]}";

$hora = $match[3];
```

Veja no [**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/lH9nY9/1)